# MediaRecorder SetNextOutputFile() dropping frames on transition?

Tags: android-mediarecorder

Is anyone else seeing dropped video frames at transitions between recorded files using MediaRecorder.SetNexVideoFile()?

For a continuous chunked video recording application I am calling SetNextVideoFile() upon receiving a MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_APPROACHING notification (having called SetMaxFileSize prior to Prepare()). I see a few frames dropped at the transition of each new file.

I have examined my individual files by demultiplexing audio and video (h.264 + AAC .mp4) and inspecting their track durations separately. There is no apparent loss of audio samples, but the video tracks are missing a few frames on each file and are consequently shorter in duration. This adversely affects efforts to play the chunks back seamlessly, e.g. with the ExoPlayer2 ConcatenatingMediaSource or other playback and postprocessing tools; file transitions result in visible hiccups.

I have tried a variety of maximum file sizes corresponding to durations of 10 seconds to 10 minutes. The dropping of frames is found at all of these file sizes.

Comment: I have also experienced this issue. When I concatenate my video files there is a noticeably skip at the seam where they files are joined due to several missing frames.